# Transducers in Swift

Tags: swift, haskell, functional-programming

I was learning functional programming in Swift through Haskell and came across this interesting concept of Transducers. One code example implemented a `mapping` function that basically spits out a Transducer, given that we pass the transformation rule as a parameter.

Inspired, I quickly translated this to a Swift equivalent and this is what I got:

```
func mapping < A, B, C> (f: A -> B) -> ( ( (C,B) -> C) -> ( (C,A) -> C) ) {
    return { r in
        return { result, a in
            return r(result,f(a))

        }

    }
}
```

My question now is that notice how the transformation function goes from A to B ( `(A -> B)` ), but the transducer goes from B to A ( `( (C,B) -> C) -> ( (C,A) -> C)` )? Why is that? I'm sure that this is not coincidental, because that order matters. Haskell experts, anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at where the call to `f` actually takes place. It's transforming an `A` to a `B`, and the result is used as an argument to `r`. Therefore `r` must be expecting a `B`; we're using an `A -> B` function to preprocess the input to a `(C, B) -> C` function, resulting in a `(C, A) -> C` function.

In general this reversal happens whenever we're transforming a system to change its "input". If we're transforming a system to change its "output", there is no reversal<sup>1</sup>.

```
X -> A   --->   A -> B   --->   B -> Y
```

If I have an `A -> B` function and I want to make from it something that emits `Y`s instead, I need to map a over it's output `B -> Y` function. This is known as *covariance*, because the thing I want to change (the `B` in `A -> B`) "varies with" the function I map over it (`B -> Y`). The `B` is said to be in a positive position in `A -> B`.

If I have an `A -> B` function and I want to make from it something that takes `X`s instead, I need to map a `X -> A` function over its input. This is known as *contravariance*, because the thing I want to change (the `A` in `A -> B`) "varies against" the function I map over it (`X -> A`). The `A` is said to be in a negative position in `A -> B`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Higher order programming means that we can be transforming a system to change an input within the output of something that's an input to an outpu "of our system...! The terms "negative position" and "positive position" help hint that the negative of a negative is a positive, etc.

Comment: Took a while to get this answer. Had to refresh my Engineering Mathematics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The order is inverted because your `mapping` is acting on the argument. You are using an `A -> B` function to make a `(C,A)` pair fit the type of a `(C,B) -> C` function. So what you get in the end is a `(C,A) -> C` function which converts the `A` in the pair to a `B` as a preliminary step.

On a more general note, `mapping` provides an example of a *contravariant functor*, as opposed to covariant functors (e.g. Haskell's `Functor` class) in which the order is not inverted. For the sake of illustration, here is a [relevant Haskell package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.3.2/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html).

Comment: To add to this answer, contravariance happens when the type variables appear in "negative" positions - that is, to the left of the function arrow. Covariance happens when the type variables appear on the right side of the function arrow. In this case the type variables are `A` and `B`. We have contravariance here because in `(C,B) -> C` and (C,A) -> C` both `A` and `B` are in negative positions.